# Validar número con expresiones regulares en C#

Tags: c#, regex

Estoy intentando crear una expresión regular para validar un número de identificación y hasta ahora llegue a lo siguiente:

```
@"^[0-9]{3}[\.][0-9]{3}[\.][0-9]{3}-[0-9]{2}$|(^[0-9]{1}[0-9]{9}[0-9]{1}$)"
```

El número de identificación en cuestión puede ser formado de las siguientes dos formas:

- 123.456.789-12
- 12345678912

Con la primera no tengo problemas, consigo validarlo perfectamente, pero con la segunda tengo el problema que no se como restringir que la cadena sea solo válida con esos 11 números.

Es decir, la secuencia `123456789123` también es válida, pero a mi no me sirve, necesito que sean exactamente 11 número de longitud.

Comment: La expresión más sencilla para 11 caracteres sería esta `^\d{11}$`

Comment: @RaptoR Si bien hay algunas cosas que se pueden mejorar de tu regex, la expresión coincide con *exactamente* 11 dígitos, ni más ni menos... Por lo que supongo que es alguna otra cosa en tu código...¿Podrías agregarlo? ... Por cierto, para responderme, usa una @ antes de mi nombre, así me llega como notificación

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta porque **es un error que no se puede reproducir**. La expresión coincide con el texto deseado (demo: http://rextester.com/WMJC61040). El autor debería publicar el código que está usando para ver un [mcve] del problema.

Answer (score 1):

Si no te he entendido mal lo que quieres es simplemente:

```
 ^((\d{3}\.\d{3}\.\d{3}-\d{2})|\d{11})$
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es el sentido de responder antes de siquiera saber el lenguaje de programación? Por ejemplo, `\d` no solo son dígitos del 0 al 9 en algunos lenguajes.

Comment: en realidad no estoy buscando simplificar mi expresion regular, utilice [0-9] porque es bien generico, pero igual \d me sirve. En realidad mi pregunta viene dada por "limitar" la respuesta correcta a 11 caracteres numéricos exactos, ni mas ni menos.

Comment: En C# esta expresión coincide con `᧙٧௯꘡६៣߆٩໖૫௫`